# How to modify values of 2 dimensional parameter in a Model

Tags: anylogic

I need to show data in tabular format in an AnyLogic Model layout, but we don't have **Table** in Anylogic.
I found one model in Anylogic Cloud which created Table in Anylogic,I added that table agent class in my model.

Link for Table Model in cloud: https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/72d3b20c-584a-4221-9ad3-d702855f7e8a?mode=SETTINGS

I successfully added Table in my Model with that agent class. Now I want to modify/insert my data in that table in model layout.

That user has created data parameter with row, column argument. But I am not getting how to insert the data in the each cells of that table. So that I can populate my data in table in model layout.

I tried
`table1.data[i][1] = "Hi2";`
`table1.set_data(i,0,"Hi1");`
`table1.Data[i][2] = "Hi3";`

I don't have my data in database table , I have data in model

Comment: Suggest you more details on how the cloud model is supposed to work, no time to check for you :). Then, show your data and we should be able to help. (Always aim to make our lives easy, not yours, see https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow )

Comment: Thx. But this does not really make my life easier :) Please improve your original question with more screenshots... What have you tried, actual errors you get, the working model setup, your data setup... Put yourself in my position: I am very happy to help but busy as hell :) The best question I can answer with 1 word, the 2nd best question I can answer with 1 sentence :)

Comment: The table agent is defined in cloud model as following. Data parameter in Table Agent  is defined with taking argument row and column as following https://imgur.com/zc7k7eN       He has created the object of that table class in main as following and assigning the value of data variable as `row + ":" + column`. https://imgur.com/qSFrUBi        Finally the table comes like this as below https://imgur.com/KTkCGFu      And my data is as below which I want to show in this table    https://imgur.com/uCEeh0d

Answer (score 1):

This table can only print `int` values, so you won't get far with your data. Also, it is very hard (and not advised) to loop through dbase table columns (like you'd need to do for this).

Better think of a different way to display your table data...

You can use replicated text objects, for example (check other example models)

Or create a simple agent type `MyTableCell` and instantiate it with some parameterized text to be displayed (i.e. a String parameter). Then, position it in xy coordinates and fill it by looping through your dbase table row by row.